# How to detect extraneous semi-colon in URL in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

My Spring MVC application has many public-facing pages with URLs in this format:

`http://www.example.com/?productId=123456`

Somewhere along the way, a major search engine picked up an extraneous URL and started spidering thousands of pages with a corrupt URL (note the `;`) in this format:

`http://www.example.com/;?productId=123456`

Strangely, Spring MVC completely ignores the `;`. How can I detect this extraneous `;` and issue a redirect to the correct URL?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently nothing available in Spring MVC, so I just placed a simple ServletFilter in front of it.